# Can't update titleView image in App Delegate (Swift)

Tags: swift, appdelegate, titleview

I want a logo to be present throughout my app. My entire app has an embedded Navigation Controller so I figured that I could set this image in the app delegate like so:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().topItem?.titleView = imageView
```

But it doesn't appear to be working. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? What did you expect to see, what did you see instead? If we have to guess what isn't working then you are unlikely to get useful answers.

Comment: You are changing the `titleView` of the `topItem` at a particular moment in time. As soon as you push or pop a view controller from that navigation controller stack the `topItem` will change.

Comment: Hey Jonah The image is not displaying at all.

Comment: @Jonah, Thanks Jonah but is there not a way to set a global setting to all Navigation Controllers? I am able to change the background color of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this using `appearance()` API.

Instead, you either have to provide an image view for each controller's navigation item's title view, or you can subclass `UINavigationBar` to add an image view that will always be there, regardless of what is in the navigation item. Then set all your controllers' titles to nil/empty string.